# Sending a POST request with chai sends an empty body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, knex.js

I have the following setup right now

test.js

```
     var user = {
        username: 'test_user',
        email: 'test@test.me',
        password: 'you shall not pass',
        address: 'No where street'
     };
     chai.request(app)
        .post('/api/v1/users')
        .send(user);
```

I'm handling the post request in my routes/user.js

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('body: ' + req.body);
    queries.insertUser(req.body)
        .then(function(id) {
            return queries.getSingleUser(id);
        })
        .then(function(user) {
            res.status(200).json(user);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            next(err);
        });
});
```

req.body ends up being undefined. Any clue as to what might be going wrong?

The code is live at https://ide.c9.io/burtonium/node-from-scratch if anybody wants to have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.body` being undefined is generally caused by either not using the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware in Express, or declaring it incorrectly (for instance, *after* the route that wants to access `req.body`).

Assuming that Chai sends JSON, add this to your Express app:

```
app.use(require('body-parser').json());
```

(before you declare the routers)

Comment: as a side note chai's reporting on server errors is pretty unhelpful. Any way to change that?

Comment: @MathieuBertin no idea, tbh, I never used `chai-http` :)

Comment: Why was I able to get a json with a simple get request? Why is body-parser necessary in this case?

Comment: @MathieuBertin `body-parser` is the middleware that parses `POST` data (and populates `req.body` with it).